# Find a basis for $w=\{f\in P_4 : f(1)=f(3)=0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

so i am a newbie in linear-algebra and don't know how to find a basis in subspace. the question is find a basis for $w=\{f\in P_4 : f(1)=f(3)=0\}$ where $P_4$ is Polynomial with the maximum power of 4, in other words it is: $a_0 + a_1x^1 + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4$.

please walk me trough the steps to find basis and proof that the found basis is for $P_4$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is $P_4$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, $P_4$ is Polynomial with maximum power of 4 in other words: $a_0 + a_1x^1 + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4$

Comment: The add that information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4$, then$$p(1)=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\text{, and }p(3)=a_0+3a_1+9a_2+27a_3+81a_4.$$But\begin{multline}\left\{\begin{array}{l}a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=0\\a_0+3a_1+9a_2+27a_3+81a_4=0\end{array}\right.\iff\\\iff a_3=\frac1{27}(-40a_0-39a_1-36a_2)\text{ and }a_4=\frac1{27}(13a_0+12a_1+9a_2).\end{multline}So, you will get a basis if you consider these $3$ polynomials: the one with $a_0=1$, $a_1=0$, and $a_2=0$, the one with $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, and $a_2=0$, and the one with $a_0=0$, $a_1=0$ and $a_2=1$. For instance, the first of these will be$$1-\frac{40}{27}x^3+\frac{13}{27}x^4.$$

Comment: can you please write, which 3 polynomials do you mean?

Comment: @mathguruu The first one appears at the end of my answer, the second one is$$x-\frac{13}9x^3+\frac49x^4,$$and the third one is$$x^2-\frac43x^3+\frac13x^4.$$

Comment: thank you! I am sorry, but can I ask one more question? Now I try to understand concept of basis and I can find a basis with another strategy, so your strategy with puting $a_0=1, a_1=0, a_2=0$ is a little bit difficult for me and new. Can we put another numbers? For example $a_1=5, a_2=7$ how do you think your choice of constant, which you will put? So basis is $(1,x,x^2,(-\frac{40}{27}-\frac{13}{9}-\frac{4}{3})x^3,(-\frac{13}{27}-\frac{4}{9}-\frac{1}{3})x^4)$. Am I right? Or how can we get the basis from these three polynomials?

Comment: @mathguruu How can a $3$-dimensional space have a basis with five elements? Besides, *none* of those five polynomials actually belong to the given space $w$. Take, for instance, $P(x)=1$, which the first polynomial from your set. But $P(1)=1\ne0$. That's why it doesn't belong to $w$.

Comment: hm, yes you are right. I am so tired, that I don't see obviously things. But the second one has to be in $w$ since $p(1)=p(3)=0$. So this one has the form of $w$, $x-\frac{13}{9}x^3+\frac{4}{9}x^4$ or?

Comment: moreover another two are also in $w$. So I can take every of this vectors and they will be a basis. Ok, I understood it. But why did you put the number 1 and 0? Because it's simple way? So in theory I can take any numbers, what I want?

Comment: @mathguruu The second one is $P(x)=x$. So, $P(1)=1\ne0$ and therefore it also doesn't belong to $w$.

Comment: I mean every of yours polynomial $\in w$, so each of yours three polynomials is the basis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141871/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-mathguruu).